# Android - error while trying to launch: ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm trying to luanch my application, and this is the log:

```
[2012-03-07 19:45:12 - hhs] Android Launch!
[2012-03-07 19:45:12 - hhs] adb is running normally.
[2012-03-07 19:45:12 - hhs] Performing hhs.pack.HhsActivity activity launch
[2012-03-07 19:45:15 - hhs] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2012-03-07 19:45:15 - hhs] Starting activity hhs.pack.HhsActivity on device emulator-5554
[2012-03-07 19:45:16 - hhs] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=hhs.pack/.HhsActivity }
[2012-03-07 19:45:16 - hhs] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=hhs.pack/.HhsActivity } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires null
```

I've been searching for some answers and understood that the problem is from my manifest file. The problem is that **I didn't touch my manifest for a long time (and it works today with the same manifest.**
Anyway, as I assume the manifest is important, this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="hhs.pack"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".HhsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" >


    </activity>
    <activity android:name="SimpleServiceActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <service android:name=".Service.SimpleService"></service>

   </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

The weird thing is:

```
[2012-03-07 19:45:15 - hhs] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
```

That sound like your app ist deployed. Try to manually deploy it or increase the versionCode.

Try

```
adb install -r
```

so he will deploy even if the versionCode is equal or higher to your current versionCode

**EDIT**

Try to replace this line

```
<activity android:name="SimpleServiceActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

with this one:

```
<activity android:name=".SimpleServiceActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Or where ever the package with the activity is located. The important thing here is the [.] before your Activity. Without that it is unknown that your Activity is in the root package.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
He deployes the app with no problem (if i'll uninstall the app, he will deploy it again). I tried to increase the version code - there is no change.

Comment: Thanks again, but it didn't solve the problem. I really think that the problem isn't in the manifest cause I didn't change him when the problem began.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your app listed in the application nodes.  I've had many a times tried to figure out why an app wouldn't run when it was as simple as that.
Also check that you have an intent filter on the activity for android.intent.action.SEARCH
and make sure you have the meta filters:

```
        <meta-data android:resource="@xml/searchable" 
        android:name="android.app.searchable"></meta-data>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".MyActivity" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My application does not contain any search function.... I don't understand the solution.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to implement a search function that wouldn't run.